# Difference betweet Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1) and $collection->getFirstItem();

Tags: magento-1.8

I have to load some products... The (my) traditional way to load a product is:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Now I have the problem, that some products can be loaded by this way - but some not.

I'm sure, there is no difference between those products... Simple, enabled, Catalag/Search, on Stock...

So - this doesn't work:

```
    $productId = '133110';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($productId);
    $price = $product->getPrice();
```

But this works:

```
    $productId = '133110';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
        ->getFirstItem();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
```

Why???

Comment: What is the product's stock status? is it in stock?

Comment: what difference you get when you dump the data?
try $price =  $product['price']; for first option

Comment: There is another module, wich uses the event catalog_product_collection_load_before, filtering Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection by an attribute. So it seems, that the first method is affected by this event, the second not. Hm...

Answer (score 3):

Your question contains answer. In table **catalog_product_entity** there is no field with price for a product. So, you can't use method get price. When you get a collection, you link **catalog_product_entity** with **catalog_product_entity_decimal**, from where it takes attribute for price.
By the way, this collection will take only price for the first store, so you should add store to filter (by **addStoreFilter()**) if you use multiple stores.
The other way - you can make your first code work, if you use flat tables for products. In this case you will use **catalog_product_flat** table, there field price is already included.

Comment: I use the flat tables. I was wondering, why some products can be load by ->load($id), but some not. The reason is, that another module is filtering the collection and Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() is not effected by this, but so Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()

Comment: Try to reindex products.

Comment: Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() collects data from multiple tables in DB. ->load($id), if flat is enabled, use only one flat table, and this table is filled only in reindex process.

Answer (score 2):

### [Edited]

In a simple word, we can say

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)` is  object of Magento product class `Mage_Catalog_Product_Model`.

Where ,`$collection->getFirstItem()` is  object of Magento product collection class `Mage_Catalog_Product_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` 
  or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection`.

### The difference between those two depends on magento flat setting

I  try to describe my point of view  in below

### When use Product flat setting enable:

**Table:**

```
`getFirstItem()`,product  has been load from `catalog_product_flat_STOREID` table.

`load()`, product is load from  product master table `catalog_product_entity` with  join with `multiple models,modules`.
```

**Attributes:**

```
**getFirstitem:** You can only get `few product attributes values Whose setting is enable for Use in Product listing.
```

load():`get all attribute`values  of a particular product with inventory prices,tax etc in full details.`

**Speedup:**

```
**getFirstitem:** it more firster ,because of  `data is coming  from single table`.

`load()` surely slow  because `multiple eav tables join,multiple module join like tax,inventory etcs`
```

### When disable product Flat setting:

**Table:**

```
`getFirstItem():` product has `been load from catalog_product_entity  table and join multiple eav,products eav using` 
function like `addAttributeToSelect,addAttributeToSort,addAttributeToFilter()` etc. 

`load()` same `beehive whenever flat is enable`
```

**Attributes:**

```
`getFirstitem:`You can get `only those attribute value whose are  select via addAttributeToSelect.,addUrlRewriteToResult() etc.`

`load():` get `all attribute values  of a particular product with inventory prices, tax etc in full details`.
```

**Speedup:**

```
`getFirstitem:` T`otaly depend on attribute selection and join product t related models`.

load() s`urely slow  because multiple eav tables join, multiple module join like tax, inventory etc`.
```

As per my point view ,`it totally depends on  attribute selection,filter etc  of product`. If your attribute `value is filled collection then you need to use collection`.

`Otherwise use Product model load`. `Because of collection is not enable giving all data.`

Comment: More details will
 provide soon